# Check if object exists in tree of objects

Tags: php, json

After decoding JSON string I'll get a lot of nested objects. For example

```
{
    clients:
    {
        latest:
        {
            business:
            {
                name:
                {

                }
            },
            personal:
            {
                name:
                {

                }
            }
        },
        first:
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to access i.e. `$result->clients->latest->business->name`

If `latest` doesn't exist then I'll get a notice that I'm trying to get property of non-object (because `latest` doesn't exist thus is non-object, hence I can't call `->name`).

How can I check if the 'object path' exists without doing

```
isset($result) ? isset($result->clients) ? isset($result->clients->latest) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array=json_decode($result,true);
if(isset($array['clients']['latest']['business']['name']))
{
 //do something...
}
```

By `json_decode($result,true)` function you can convret the json to array and then just check if the value is set or not.

Comment: thats a nice way but its a comment, please explain more to get a good answer which can be +1'ed

Answer (score 0):

Use a try catch :

```
try{  
    $name= $result->clients->latest->business->name;
}catch(Exception $e){
    $name = '';
}
```